# The code always iterate over the first tag and skips the rest or it prints nothing

Tags: python, xml

I'm really stuck here.
The result would be it would print the text attached to the 'string' tag beside the 'key' tag with the text 'Name'
here's an example:

```
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2015-11-24T11:12:10Z</date>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>12.3.1.23</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Music Folder</key><string>file:///Users/csev/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/</string>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>B7006C9E9799282E</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>369</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>369</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Another One Bites The Dust</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Queen</string>
```

here's the code:

```
`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file_name = 'Library.xml'


def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found:
            return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key:
            found = True
        return None


stuff = ET.parse(file_name)
all_stuff = stuff.findall('dict/dict/dict')
print("File Count:", len(all_stuff))

for entry in all_stuff:
    if lookup(entry, 'Track ID') is None:
        continue
    name = lookup(entry, 'Name')
    print(name)`
```

here's the result if you run it:

```
File Count: 404

Process finished with exit code 0
```

it doesn't print the name, and if you use the .find('string'). It always print the 1st string tag and skips the 2nd string tag.

the result should be:

```
File count: 404
Another One Bites The Dust
```

or if you run artist = lookup(entry, 'Artist') print(artist)
the result should be:

```
Queen
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with indentation in this loop:

```py
    for child in d:
        if found:
            return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key:
            found = True
        return None
```

It looks like the last line is indented too much, which means that if neither of the first two conditions match, your method returns.

You probably want to unindent the last line so that it only runs once the `for child in d` loop finishes:

```py
    for child in d:
        if found:
            return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key:
            found = True
    return None
```

Comment: OMG! That was it?!! Thank you very much!!! I was stuck at this problem for about 5 hours now.